# Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted

Tags: java, linux, lua

got an error when calling lua

below are gdb info

> Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
> #0  0x00007f029cc9b387 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6

```sh
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f029cc9b387 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f029cc9ca78 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f029e78b389 in os::abort(bool) () from /project/libs/jdk1.8.0/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007f029e954303 in VMError::report_and_die() () from /project/libs/jdk1.8.0/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007f029e795635 in JVM_handle_linux_signal () from /project/libs/jdk1.8.0/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007f029e7884d8 in signalHandler(int, siginfo*, void*) () from /project/libs/jdk1.8.0/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  <signal handler called>
#7  0x00007f029f7c76a9 in luaF_close () from /project/libs/liblua/liblua.so
#8  0x00007f029f7cf258 in luaE_freethread () from /project/libs/liblua/liblua.so
#9  0x00007f029f7c8b53 in sweeplist () from /project/libs/liblua/liblua.so
#10 0x00007f029f7c8c6a in sweepstep () from /project/libs/liblua/liblua.so
#11 0x00007f029f7c937e in luaC_step () from /project/libs/liblua/liblua.so
#12 0x00007f029f7d31a7 in luaV_execute () from /project/libs/liblua/liblua.so
#13 0x00007f029f7c677f in luaD_call () from /project/libs/liblua/liblua.so
#14 0x00007f029f7c67d1 in luaD_callnoyield () from /project/libs/liblua/liblua.so
#15 0x00007f029f7c5c1f in luaD_rawrunprotected () from /project/libs/liblua/liblua.so
#16 0x00007f029f7c6abd in luaD_pcall () from /project/libs/liblua/liblua.so
#17 0x00007f029f7c23de in lua_pcallk () from /project/libs/liblua/liblua.so
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Apparently some assert failed and the process asked for termination.

Comment: Probably Lua was trying to free a wrong pointer.